# GD&T Is this a regular feature of size?

Tags: drafting

From ASME-Y14.5, a regular feature of size is defined as "one cylindrical surface, a spherical surface, a circular element, or a set of two opposed parallel line elements or opposed parallel surfaces associated with a single directly toleranced dimension". Is the following a regular feature of size?
[image: draft]

Does this qualify as a "circular element" thus making it a regular feature of size?

Comment: Looks like 6 concentric circular elements to me. Depending on the function of the surfaces, they may require e.g. a concentricity tolerance.